# select how many DEPTNO's exists for each LOC plus number of EMP's

Tags: sql, oracle

I guess messed up the joins...

Single DEPT has many LOCations, every DEPT should have a sum of its EMPs. I need to show DISTINCT LOCs, number of LOCs per DEPT and sum of EMPS in each DEPT - without dividing the locations.

With tables DEPT & EMP like this:

```
SELECT DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC FROM DEPT;

10  ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
20  RESEARCH    DALLAS
30  SALES       CHICAGO
40  OPERATIONS  BOSTON
50  NONE        DALLAS

select ENAME, DEPTNO from EMP;

SMITH   20
ALLEN   30
WARD    30
JONES   20
MARTIN  30
BLAKE   30
CLARK   10
SCOTT   20
KING    10
TURNER  30
ADAMS   20
JAMES   30
FORD    20
MILLER  10
CURT    40
```

Can't properly add the below subquery into my WITH... clause below. Need to select how many DEPTNO's exists for each LOC plus give a number of EMP's in each *DEPT* like here (plus location number) - it should use 2 different kinds of summaries in:

```
select e.deptno, count(e.deptno) from emp e
group by e.deptno;

10  3
20  5
30  6
40  1
```

Here is what I did:

```
WITH workers_per_dept as
  (SELECT
  d.LOC LOC,
  d.deptno DEPTNO,
  count(e.empno) EMP_NUMBER
  FROM dept d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN emp e ON (e.deptno = d.deptno)
  GROUP BY d.LOC,d.deptno 
  ORDER BY d.deptno)
select 
  d.LOC LOCATION, 
  count(d.LOC) LOCATIONS_PER_DEPT, 
  workers_per_dept.EMP_NUMBER 
from DEPT d, workers_per_dept
WHERE d.LOC = workers_per_dept.LOC
GROUP BY d.LOC, workers_per_dept.EMP_NUMBER
ORDER BY 1;
```

I receive this (should be groupped by LOC with):

```
BOSTON      1   1
CHICAGO     1   6
DALLAS      2   0
DALLAS      2   5
NEW YORK    1   3
```

(result should have not repeated LOC's - 'DALLAS        2   0' should be skipped)

Comment: Could you show how a desired result should look like ? It's not clear how do you want to lay out these information in one resultset ?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my mothers tongue, It should look like last gray area without 'DALLAS 2 0'

Comment: 1 DEPT has many LOCations, every DEPT should has sum of its EMPs. I need to show DISTINCT LOCs, number of LOCs per DEPT and sum of EMPS in each DEPT - without dividing the locations.

Comment: So what is the correct output you need? Can you edit your question with the output you desire? Thank you.

Comment: I think you're looking for a row to simultaneously represent a location and a department. It's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query. You need to group by location and count distinct occurrences of Dept's in each group:

```
select d.loc,
       count(distinct d.deptno) depts,
       count(e.ename) emps
from dept d
left join emp e on d.deptno = e.deptno
group by d.loc
```

Comment: but count(distinct d.deptno) depts gives always 1

Comment: @mallorn, of  course, there should be left join. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me... but finally did it myself
it was so easy...

```
SELECT d.LOC LOCATION,
(select count(d.LOC) FROM DEPT l WHERE l.LOC=d.LOC) LOCS,
(select count(e.deptno) FROM EMP e WHERE e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO) EMPS
FROM DEPT d;
```

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: Although it doesn't make any real difference it's a little silly to use `d.LOC` at the argument to `count()` since that comes from the outer query.